# What's the meaning of "therethen"?

Tags: word-in-context

I'm studyng the content found on another question on this site and the expression "therethen" is used on some sentences in the answers. In one of the examples it's explained as being related to "spacetime state" but it doesn't help me to understand it. I have alread spent some time doing researches but I just can't understand what it really means. Here are some of the sentences I'm talking about:

> B could have stop the accident from moving to therethen
>
> B could have kept therethen away from the accident
>
> B could have stop therethen from moving to the accident
>
> "The accident could have been prevented by driving carefully." =
>   "Driving carefully could have stop the accident from moving to
>   therethen."

Answer (score 3):

*Therethen* is not an established word, so it doesn't have an established meaning. (It is not in the OED or in English Wiktionary).

If somebody uses it, they can use it with any meaning they want. Your guess is as good as anybody else's as to what they did mean.

Comment: Why not just say it does not exist?

Comment: @Lambie But *does* it?

Comment: Somebody has apparently intentionally used it. Ergo, it exists.

Answer (score 1):

You **could** improve the grammar by changing every "stop" into "stopped", but it seems futile. We really need to address the **therethen**!

You must have been [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/52710/the-difference-between-prevent-and-avoid/146064), at StackExchange. I have no idea what Pacerier is talking about, but
[this site](http://creategreaterlives.com/the-power-of-herenow-vs-therethen-in-manifesting/) shows you how to focus your mental energy in a way that the universe can react to it. That's *always* worth doing. When you've got the hang of it we'll be happy to help you with your English. Good luck!